# How to set developer option after reboot?

Tags: root-access, developer-options

My phone reboots upon BT connection if I don't set the BT codec to SBC. I've been messing w/ Tasker to automate this upon reboot, but I have root access, is there any way to set this programmatically to stick? It seems it gets re-set often back to "best effort"/default. Ideally, this would be perhaps a one off script, or a script that Tasker can call upon reboot vs using "sendkeys/autoinput".

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unofficial-havocos-3-5-for-the-lg-v40.4104753/page-2#post-85607441

Answer (score 1):

Try dialing code *#*#4636#*#* into your phone. No need to press the send call button. After the last * is input, the pop up screen will automatically display. Choose option usually displays (PHONE INFORMATION).
Then you can modify an update a connection your having issues with.

There is so much information and a vast amount of ways you can go about fixing your device. That said, I simply can't go into in-depth detail pertaining to your issue, so best option is to search the information you don't understand once you enter the configuration pages.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool menu! I will save that special code as it seems to be version independent which is nice! But, I saw no way to manipulate BT settings. On the other hand, this did get me wondering if I can access the other menus, but its a custom ROM from Pixel 4 so I think I'll look up that device.